# HTML5 geolocation watchPosition getting called just once

Tags: html, geolocation

I am creating an android application using html 5 and  I want to access latlong from the user as the user moves. I have used watchPostion but it isgiving me user location just once.

```
    var watchID;
var geoLoc;

function showLocation(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var ll=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    map.setCenter(ll);

  console.log("Latitude : " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude);
}

function errorHandler(err) {
  if(err.code == 1) {
    console.log("Error: Access is denied!");
  }else if( err.code == 2) {
    console.log("Error: Position is unavailable!");
  }
    }
    if(navigator.geolocation){
      // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
      var options = {timeout:60000};
      geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
      watchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(showLocation, 
                                     errorHandler,
                                     options);


   }else{
      console.log("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been working on something similar a few months ago. I remember having the same issue. Maybe this will help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    initLocationProcedure();
}

function initLocationProcedure() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom : 17
    });

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError, {
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            timeout : 60000,
            maximumAge : 0
        });
    } else {
        alert("Your phone does not support the Geolocation API");
    }
}

function displayAndWatch(position) {
    // set current position
    setUserLocation(position);
    // watch position
    watchCurrentPosition();
}

function setUserLocation(pos) {
    // marker for userLocation
    userLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
           map : map,
           position : new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
           title : "You are here",
           icon : "../img/user-location.svg",
    // scroll to userLocation
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
});
```

Here is what you are looking for

```
function watchCurrentPosition() {
    var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        setMarkerPosition(userLocation, position);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    });
}

function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
     marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
     console.log(position);
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/XEFks/

Comment: hi Barto , I tried using your code but still having the same issue. I tried the code on mobile browser and it works fine, But on desktop browsers I get the location just once.

Comment: I've put it in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XEFks/, if you open the page and look at the console, you should see updating the location (there will be a Gelocation object in the console). It won't update every second, because at first the location is set, when a better one is found, the first one is updated and so on. (Definitely working here)

Comment: ok. So you mean if the position is not updated then i would not be able to get the position till the position changes.. So in short it's not possible to get the  location repeatedly on a desktop as it does not change its location ?

Comment: No, not directly from the navigator object. Of course, you could repeatedly call a `getCurrentPosition()` to return your coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure you call the Geolocation.clearWatch() method with the id as well so that it resets the location .

See example below:

[Web/API/Geolocation.watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.watchPosition)

The Geolocation.watchPosition() method is used to register a handler function that will be called automatically each time the position of the device changes. You can also, optionally, specify an error handling callback function.

This method returns a watch ID value than can be used to unregister the handler by passing it to the Geolocation.clearWatch() method.

Syntax

```
var id, target, option;

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  if (target.latitude === crd.latitude && target.longitude === crd.longitude) {
    console.log('Congratulation, you reach the target');
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
  }
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

target = {
  latitude : 0,
  longitude: 0,
}

options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
```

---

You could also try wrapping the clear function like below. Also setting it to null will ensure it gets updated.

```
// clear the watch that was started earlier
// 
function clearWatch() {
    if (watchID != null) {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I have used clearWatch but I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: have you used clearwatch(watchID); like this. passing in the orginal id?

Comment: Yes. I have used like that.

Comment: I have just replaced successfunction with, ` function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  if (target.latitude === crd.latitude && target.longitude === crd.longitude) {
    console.log('Congratulation, you reach the target');
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID );  watchID = null;
  }
}; `

Comment: Thank you @SoftwareCarpenter ! Working perfect. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function watchCurrentPosition() {
    var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        setMarkerPosition(userLocation, position);
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
    });
}
```

This would certainly help..